# Initializer is not constant... I know, but I feel like this should work, why doesn't it

Tags: c, gcc

The following code compiles fine if I remove the static qualifier, but I don't understand why it doesn't work otherwise. I can see the string in the .rodata section (when compiling without the static qualifier), and the final assembly just loads pointers appropriately before calling printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define S "Testing"
#define C 't'
typedef struct {
    char const * const s;
    char const c;
} foo;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static foo const f = {
        .s = S,
        .c = S[3],
    };
    printf("s = %s, c = %c\n", f.s, f.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, it compiles fine with the static qualifier if I use:

```
.c = C,
```

Interestingly, the assembly looks identical (yeah, gcc hijacks the 't' from "Testing")

This snippet is just to demonstrate the specific example I'm encountering in a much more complex problem. Why can't the compiler treat a string literal [] element as a constant, when clearly it does?

BTW, compiled with gcc 5.4 with only -O2

Edit: To clarify, the problem is the initialization of f.c

Edit: Thanks for the insights everyone. In summary, the preprocessor can't do anything with strings, which is lame. If I actually implement what I am trying to do in the scope of a function, the compiler (with optimization) will eventually process everything down to constants in the .rodata section, but I can't accomplish the same at the global scope, unfortunately.

Solution: Write a custom python script (or whatever your favorite scripting language is) to generate code, or use c++

Comment: To clarify, the problem is the initialization of f.c

Comment: Edit your clarification into the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C language objects with static storage duration require *constant expressions* as initializers. `S[3]` is not a constant expression in C. You are basically not allowed to "read from memory" in constant expressions, i.e. you are not allowed to use unary `*` operator and, consequently, not allowed to use `[]` operator to read array elements.

Meanwhile, `'t'` is immediately a constant, which is why your code compiles when you replace `S[3]` with `C`.

Comment: Why though? If S is a const expression, how hard is it to treat S[i] as a const expression. It is literally *((&S) + sizeof(S[0]) * i)

Comment: @Scott Valentine: Yes, you are right, it should not be hard for the compiler to figure out what `"Testing"[3]` is in this specific case. However, the general rules of C constant expressions prohibit `[]` operator in this context. No exception is made for "obvious" situations.

Comment: well, I guess I'm minorly hosed then... I up voted your answer, but I got no rep.

Comment: I think that the relevant section of the standard is ISO/IEC 9899:2011 6.6/9: "The array-subscript **[]**... may be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be accessed by use of these operators."

Comment: @ScottValentine: `const` and "constant" are two very different things. `const` just means "read-only". A constant expression is one that's required to be evaluated at compile time. An example of the difference: `const int r = rand();`.

Comment: @AnT-- I have added my own answer that proposes a modification to OP's `struct` as a solution to the problem. It is clear that you know your way around this stuff, and I would appreciate any thoughts that you might care to offer.

Comment: @David Bowling: Your answer is perfectly correct. It is just a question of whether the proposed change is acceptable for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

From C11 6.7.9/4 (Initialization - Constraints):

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

The definition of *constant expression* is found in 6.6. Specifically 6.6/7:

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.

However `S[3]` is none of those. An arithmetic constant expression is only allowed to have operands that are constants of arithmetic type (in brief), however `S[3]` means `*(S + 3)` which has a pointer operand.

Using `'t'` as initializer is fine, that is a character constant and therefore an arithmetic constant expression.

Note: *constant expression* has a quite separate meaning to "`const`-qualified variable". Constant expressions are never `const`-qualified and are a disjoint set from variables and objects.

---

Possibly the language could have been defined so that indexing a string literal with a valid index counts as a constant expression, but it wasn't.

Note that string literals are not constant expressions (although their address is). They are arrays of non-const `char` . There is also a rule that it is undefined behaviour to modify a string literal. So portable code has to treat a string literal as if it were `const`, although technically it is not. Historically some compilers have allowed modification of string literals.

Comment: More significant than than the fact that some compilers have "allowed" modification of string literals is the fact that some compilers have documented behavior in such cases even though the Standard does not require them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your eventual goal is, but maybe this small change in your `struct` can help. According to the standard:

> The array-subscript **[ ]** and member-access **.** and **->**
>   operators, the address **&** and indirection ***** unary operators,
>   and pointer casts may be used in the creation of an address constant,
>   but the value of an object shall not be accessed by the use of these
>   operators.
>   ISO/IEC 9899:2011 6.6/9

In the code from your example, you attempt to use the value of `S[3]` in an initializer as a constant expression. The above shows why this is not possible, but you can use the *address* of `S[3]` as a constant expression:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define S "Testing"
#define C 't'
typedef struct {
    char const * const s;
    char const * const c;
} foo;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static foo const f = {
        .s = S,
        .c = &S[3],
    };
    printf("s = %s, c = %c\n", f.s, *(f.c));
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this code, the output is:

```
s = Testing, c = t
```

Answer (score -5):

You're problem is that define does not initialise just used in preprocessor. You would need:

```
static const char *S = "Testing/0";
static const char C = 't';
```

Comment: No, what I am actually trying to accomplish is using the preprocessor to compile things down to a true static constant value (.rodata), and my blocking issue is that it doesn't treat array elements as constant expressions, but it does treat an array as a constant expression...

Your example could never be uses as a static initializer for something else, and the '\0' is always implicit (well, unless you use a fixed array size).

Comment: Fixed it should be const!

Comment: I think you are missing the point... I have no problem initializing f.s, the problem is f.c. In your example, *S is fine, sure, but it can never be used as a static initializer for something else.

Comment: Fixed C should be const as well.

Comment: @koper89: This will not achieve anything at all.

Comment: Why you think not, @AnT?

Comment: @koper89: In C language `const` objects are not *constants*. They cannot be used to initialize objects with static storage duration. E.g. `const int a = 5; static int b = a;` will not compile in C.

Comment: Yep but two separately will compile.

Comment: @koper89: Um... What does "two separately" mean? How do you "separate" `static int b = a;` when it relies on `a`?

Comment: I'm saying that in my example they are not relying on each other.

Comment: @koper89: But the ultimate purpose of this question is to initialize the OP's `static foo const f`. The OP does not have any issues with `S` or `C`. The OP is getting an error in the declaration of `static foo const f`. What is the point of changing `S` and `C`, if it will not help with the error at all? (This is what I meant when I said that "This will not achieve anything at all").

Comment: And I'm saying replace it with mine, the other one delete and it'll work.

Comment: @koper89: Wrong. It will not. Your `const` objects cannot be used to initialize `static foo const f`. That's the whole point of my comments. Try it and see for yourself.